# Insertar una fecha en MySQL que está en un formato diferente al de Date

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

El formato por default en el que se trabaja en `MySQL` a cuanto fechas es `%Y-%m-%d`.

Yo quisiera saber ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para insertar una fecha con el formato `%d/%m/%Y`? o si existe alguna forma para configurar la columna de mi base de datos y se establezca el formato de fecha anterior.

Comment: No es posible cambiar la forma en que se almacenan las fechas. Pero sí existen funciones para mostrarlas en distintos formatos desde el mysql. ¿Podrías indicar por qué es un dolor de cabeza?

Comment: @james_bond Para mi es un dolor de cabeza, ya que desde hace mucho he tratado de encontrar una solución a este problema, porque desde la interfaz gráfica a la hora de agregar las fechas tenia que modificar los datepicker, soy mexicano y el formato de fechas es distinto, por eso hoy decidí preguntar para darle solución a mi problema.

Comment: ¿Estás ingresando los datos directamente en MySQL WorkBench? ¿O desde el código en algún lenguaje de programación? Si es el 2do, deberías eliminar la etiqueta [tag:mysql-workbench] y agregar la del lenguaje que estés usando, así como agregar un [mcve] mostrando tu código, con lo que intentaste hasta ahora, por más que no funcione.

Comment: Mira puedes buscar aquí lo que buscas... http://todoprogramacion.com.ve/blog/formatear-fechas-en-mysql-con-la-funcion-date-format o bien visitar este sitio https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mysqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?inicio=0&cod=23&punto=19 Me cuentas como te fue..
Buen Día!!

Comment: Creo que enfocas mal el tema. MySql guarda la fecha como debe guardarlo y nada más. MySql no es para visualizar data, es para almacenarla. El como lo muestras en tus datapickers depende a como tienen configurado el formato de presentación, algunos frameworks como Primefaces los hacen sencillo mientras que otros tienen que hacerse manualmente. Sea cual fuere es independiente a la BD. Una buena práctica es tener un ORM que te devuelva el date de MySql en el tipo adecuado del lenguaje, ejem. java.util.Date.

Comment: @Mariano estoy trabajando en `workbench` para hacer pruebas, @DeoDeoxyseia tienes razon, gracias a las respuestas y a lo poco o mucho que he buscado, me han dado una noción del funcionamiento `MySQL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL provee un número importante de funciones para trabajar con fechas y en las que nos podemos apoyar, [puedes revisar la documentación.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Algunas de las funciones que te pueden ser de ayuda para insertar fechas o recuperarlas con un formato determinado pueden ser

`STR_TO_DATE` : convierte un string en date.  Ejemplo para insertar una fecha `dd/mm/YYYY`

```
INSERT INTO tabla (fecha) VALUES( STR_TO_DATE('31/01/2018', '%d/%m/%Y') );
```

`DATE_FORMAT`: da formato a un campo del tipo date

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%W %M %Y') FROM tabla;
```