# Insertar formulario a base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

No tengo experiencia en diseño, pero tengo este pequeño problema estoy poniendo un dato mal, favor ayuda.

Este es el formulario o solo la parte del error

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
<input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jFecha" id="single_cal4" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
<span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span id="inputSuccess2Status4" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
  </div>
```

Este es el js

```
$("#jugador-add").click(function () {
        $("#myModalj").modal();





         $("#aceptar_jugador").unbind('click');
                $("#aceptar_jugador").click(function () {


        var jNombre = document.getElementById("jNombre").value;
        var jApellido = document.getElementById("jApellido").value;
        var single_cal4 = document.getElementById("single_cal4").value;
        var jCedula = document.getElementById("jCedula").value;
        var jDireccion = document.getElementById("jDireccion").value;
        var jCiudad = document.getElementById("jCiudad").value;
        var jTelefono = document.getElementById("jTelefono").value;
        var jEstatura = document.getElementById("jEstatura").value;
        var jNumero = document.getElementById("jNumero").value;

        var jEmail = document.getElementById("jEmail").value;
        var jContraseña = document.getElementById("jContraseña").value;

        if ( jNombre == "" || jApellido == "" || single_cal4 == "" || jCedula =="" || jDireccion =="" || jCiudad =="" || jTelefono =="" || jEstatura =="" || jNumero =="" || jEmail =="" || jContraseña =="") {
                alert("Error: Todos los campos son obligatorios.");

            } else {
             $("#myModalj").modal('toggle');


        var params = {jNombre, jApellido, single_cal4, jCedula, jDireccion, jCiudad, jTelefono, jEstatura, jNumero, jEmail, jContraseña}

         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jugador-insert.php',
                data: params,
                async:true,

                    success: function(respuesta) {

                        alert("Informacion: Jugador creado correctamente!");
                        location.reload();
                             }

            });
            }
            });
        });
```

y este es el insert:

```
<?php

    $jNombre = $_POST['jNombre'];
    $jApellido = $_POST['jApellido'];
    $single_cal4 = $_POST['jFecha'];
    $jCedula = $_POST['jCedula'];
    $jDireccion = $_POST['jDireccion'];
    $jCiudad = $_POST['jCiudad'];
    $jTelefono = $_POST['jTelefono'];
    $jEstatura =$_POST['jEstatura'];
    $jNumero = $_POST['jNumero'];
    $jrefEquipo = $_POST['jrefEquipo'];
    $jrefPosicion = $_POST['jrefPosicion'];
    $jEmail = $_POST['jEmail'];
    $jContraseña = md5($_POST["jContraseña"]);

    $jregistro=date('Y-m-d');




    $sql="INSERT into tbljugadores (jNombre, jApellido, jFecha,  jCedula, jDireccion, jCiudad, jTelefono, jEstatura, jNumero, jrefEquipo, jrefPosicion, jEmail, jContraseña, jregistro)
            values ('$jNombre','$jApellido','$single_cal4','$jCedula','$jDireccion','$jCiudad','$jTelefono','$jEstatura','$jNumero','$jrefEquipo','$jrefPosicion','$jEmail','$jContraseña','$jregistro')";
    echo mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 ?>
```

La pregunta es

**¿Por qué no me guarda la fecha en la base de datos todos los campos se guardan menos la fecha?**

la bd campo `jFecha` es tipo date y el html manda los datos mes dia año

Comment: Para que la base de datos tome tu fecha debes de respetar el formato que acepta, en este caso debe ser siempre `YYYY-MM-DD` (año-mes-dia) o `YYYYMMDD`, es decir año-mes-dia con o sin guiones, cual quier otro formato fallara a no ser que realices una conversion. Puedes obtener mas informacion en la documentacion aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Hace ya algun tiempo deje una respuesta en esta pregunta [Insertar una fecha en MySQL que está en un formato diferente al de Date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135153/insertar-una-fecha-en-mysql-que-est%c3%a1-en-un-formato-diferente-al-de-date/135165#135165) para realizar la conversion en un insert, seguramente te pueda servir de orientacion

Answer (score 0):

Referente a tu problema, algunas veces no introduce debido a que la columna creada en la BBDD es en formato DATE y no insertas el dato correcto.

La solución más rápida y sencilla sería cambiar esa columna fecha de la BBDD a un campo tipo texto editando dicha columna.

Comment: Esto que dices es lo peor que puedes hacer, pues dificultará mucho el trabajo con fechas en la base de datos.